# It is possible to get data for easyui tree using ajax in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, tree, jquery-easyui

Can you tell me if it is possible to get data for easyui tree using ajax success..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create tree first
$('#tt').tree({
...
});
```

get data in your success method and use loadData method to load it in your tree

```
var data = [{...},{...}];
// then call 'loadData' method
$('#tt').tree('loadData', data);
```